# Discord.js image attachment

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const { Client, Intents, MessageAttachment, Message } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"]});
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('In sfarsit joc DnD. Ssssssp.');
});
let x = 1;

client.on('message', msg =>
{
   
    if (msg.content === "+help")
    {
        let msg1 = "You should know how to use me by now. Sssssssp. Times you were unworthy: ";
        let msg2 = x.toString();
        let msgf = msg1.concat(msg2);
        x++;
        msg.reply(msgf);
    }
    name = ["Triceps","Babuska","Dero","Special","Radw","Pucin","Eclipsentiu","Eugen","Tugen","Elgen","Ha Ha Bitch","Helium", "Saradin", "Chevrolet", "Gogo", "Cactus", "Sarkofag", "Guru", "Trubius", "Storyline", "Giorgio", "Wiggler", "Wig", "Stetoskop", "Tracu", "Mizil", "Trafalet", "Stepmom", "Yridim", "Soul","Lyfjaberg","Netflix","Gugutza","Rakshasa","Trubilion","Sufftard","Panu","Radulescu","Infatuated","Sex'n'Fund","Tuc","Streche","Nebanuit","Bust","Ecologie","Surf","Bag","0110","Pork","Fork","Redbuff"];
    let no_changed = 0;
    if (msg.content === "+exhale_the_truth")
    {
        if (Math.random() <= 0.05)
        {
            msg.reply("No. I don't think I will. Sssssssp.");
            return;
        }
        msg.reply("Look what you made me do. Sssssssp.");
        msg.guild.members.cache.forEach((a) => {
            if (!a.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
            {
                do {
                    nick = "";
                    if (Math.random() <= 0.08)
                        nick = "El ";
                    nick = nick + name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)] + ' ' + name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)] + ' ';
                    if (Math.random() <= 0.02)
                        nick = nick + "d'";
                    else
                        if (Math.random() <= 0.001)
                            nick = nick + "von";
                    nick = nick + name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)];

                }
                while (nick.length > 32)
                a.setNickname(nick);
                console.log(nick);
                no_changed++;
            }
        });
        console.log(no_changed);
       
    }
    if (msg.content === "+DnD") {
         var attc = new MessageAttachment('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Stefan_Banica_Jr.jpg');
        msg.reply(attc);
    }

});
client.login('token');
```

At

```
  if (msg.content === "+DnD") {
         var attc = new MessageAttachment('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Stefan_Banica_Jr.jpg');
        msg.reply(attc);
    }
```

Apparently this attempts to send an empty message. I just want to attach an image. It could be a path from my computer too, I don't really think I care about how it is provided or that there is a difference in the implementation. Discord.js v13 btw. Also I would prefer a pretty straightforward solution, without using too many complicated concepts if possible. Obviously anything will do.

Comment: If you haven't already, re-generate your bot's token. You shouldn't share the token with anyone, treat it like a password. Anyone with the token can gain full control of your bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `messagw.reply({files: [attc]})`
And i suggest use messageCreate event instead of message

Answer (score 1):

The reason the reply is empty is that Message.reply() does not take a MessageAttachement. It takes string, MessagePayload, or ReplyMessageOptions.

You'll have to build a [MessagePayload](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessagePayload?scrollTo=files) with files attached.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I think I will need more than that. I clicked the link and saw that options should probably be the one with the attachment so I replaced  `msg.reply(attc);` with  `mess = new MessagePayload(msg.author, attc);
        msg.channel.send(mess);` and it behaves the same .  I'm not gonna lie that fact that i am a begginer at both JS and discord.js and a CS student probably doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, you have to add the `files` property which takes an array of `MessageFile` with property of `attachement` to the payload.